# Різниця між словами "зброя" та "озброєння"

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Цікавить чи є різниця між словами "зброя" та "озброєння".
В СУМі є як і слово "[озброєння](http://sum.in.ua/s/ozbrojennja)" (де вказано, що це "військове спорядження; зброя"), так і слово "[зброя](http://sum.in.ua/s/zbroja)", однак різниця між ними не дуже зрозуміла, тим більше, що у визначення слова "озброєння" пише, що це "зброя", а коло "зброї" пише, що це "озброєння".

Також знаходжу ці слова в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F). І як синонімічні терміни на [цьому сайті](http://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/term/10062).

Однак, на Вікіпедії є дві статті - про [зброю](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) та про [озброєння](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).
Дивимось визначення останнього:

> комплекс матеріальних засобів активної (наступальної) чи пасивної
>   (захисної) дії, спрямованої на допомогу власнику у ході бойових дій.

А тепер дивимося визначення зброї:

> сукупність технічних пристроїв та засобів, що застосовується для
>   ураження живої сили противника, його техніки, спорудження та інших
>   цілей під час ведення бойових дій; **озброєння**.

Тобто зараз можна зробити висновок, що ці слова є абсолютними синонімами, але як тоді бути із такими елементами військового спорядження як щит, бронежелет, танки тощо. На Вікіпедії вони відносяться до окремих категорій "захисне озброєння" та "бойова техніка", так само маємо "[артилерійське озброєння](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)", де перераховуються різні види гармат, мінометів, додатковго обладнання (і саме ось тут у мене виникла думка, що озброєння - це ширше поняття, аніж зброя, тобто воно включає і зброю, і допоміжні засоби, наприклад, біноклі, патрони, снаряди тощо).

То чи є це абсолютні синоніми? Чи все ж є якась різниця?

Comment: [Різниця між словами _супровід_ та _супроводження_](/q/3552/). Зазначу, шчо тут шче приросток [_о_ — 15](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_pryrostky).

Answer (score 2):

"взяв на озброєння" синонім до усталеного виразу "намотав на вус", тобто на мою думку подібне до [арсеналу](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1607&page=73) або [технології](http://sum.in.ua/s/tekhnologhija). В той час як [зброя](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=34542&page=1101) це знаряддя людини.

Підсумовуючи я вважаю, що вони не є абсолютними синонімами та мають відгалуження.

Comment: зброя це знаряддя для агресії або захисту шляхом контратаки.

Comment: згоден, *озброєння* складається з наявної *зброї*